# Allow two users to commit with their usernames on the same machine

Tags: git, virtual-machine, commit

I am trying use a VM with a friend of mine for developement purposes. But since I have initialized the git repository and installed the git program, all commits are registered as my work.

Is there a way for us to commit and possibly include a user parameter to understand who did what on that same machine and git folder.

P.S.

Thank you all for your comments and making me understand what is the correct idea behind a git (one person per repo). But the main reason my friend and I are working on one VM and one repo is because we need to share one database thats on the VM. Is there then a way to by pass this without going against how git was meant to be set up (one git user per repo)?

Comment: Use git how it supposed to: Everybody should have their own clone. Working on a single checkout at the same time would just be messy.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and making me understand what is the correct idea behind a git (one person per repo). But the main reason my friend and I are working on one VM and one repo is because we need to share one database thats on the VM. Is there then a way to by pass this without going against how git was meant to be set up (one git user per repo)?

Comment: You could use docker to create a container and share the database through it. This is of course as long as you don't need to maintain the same data in the database.

Comment: Did you try making two user accounts on the VM?

Answer (score 3):

What work you do on your Git box is considered your own. It's impractical to have to switch out user name and email information for every commit as well, but it can be done.

Let me be explicit in saying that **this approach is not recommended.**  This will only induce headaches for the both of you.

Before your friend commits, adjust the parameters `user.name` and `user.email` for that repo:

```
git config user.name "<friends-name-here>"
git config user.email "<friends-email-here>"
```

This may have implications on authentication if pushing to a remote server, so be careful.

That said, what you two *really* want to do is push it to a remote repository, like [GitHub](http://github.com) or [BitBucket](http://bitbucket.com), commit to your own local repositories, then merge them together before they're pushed upstream.

Answer (score 2):

Another silly idea that should work:

Create 2 aliases "tom" and "jerry" that configure the email and the name of the committer before running the git command you want to run.

That way, each of you could use git commands like that:

```
git tom commit -a -m "my commit"
```

And

```
git jerry checkout my branch
```

The 2 aliases should look something like :

```
tom = !sh -c \"git config --global user.name "Tom" && git config --global user.email "tom@here.org" && git $*\"
```

and

```
jerry = !sh -c \"git config --global user.name "Jerry" && git config --global user.email "jerry@here.org" && git $*\"
```

Comment: hey @philippe . I like your idea and tried to execute it. When trying to set up the aliases I received a bash : !sh : event not found error. any suggestions?

Comment: Don't try to set the alias, just copy paste the aliases in the '.git/config' file in the alias section.

Comment: For a use case that makes me shudder, this solution is actually pretty good.

Comment: Philippe I started using your way but there still seems to be an issue. every single time I commit while including the alias, it gives me pathspec error. I tried not including the alias, my git commands then worked fine. Please help. I know we are close since the alias did not produce an erro

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help much in this problem because I don't know enough the unix shell. It's a problem with quotes `"`. You have 2 solutions: either don't use them (it should be a no big deal because these alias are just used for committing) or escape them with a `\ ` (so write `\"` each time). I hope that's not a too high price to pay ;)

Answer (score 1):

Git was designed with the idea of one actor per repository. Subverting this idea will introduce more problems than it will solve. **If your trying to keep all source on a single VM** you could setup a distributed workflow by creating a [bare repository](ftp://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-init.html#_options) on the VM which your deployment and the developers use as a central point of interaction.

```
# Create bare repository
git clone --bare --branch master /path/to/your/existing/repo /path/to/new/bare/repo

# Create user repositories
git clone /path/to/new/bare/repo taco_john_repo
cd taco_john_repo
git config user.name "Taco John"
git config user.email "taco_john@git-scm.org"

cd ..

git clone /path/to/new/bare/repo burrito_bill_repo
git config user.name "Burrito Bill"
git config user.email "burrito_bill@git-scm.org"

# Update existing repo to use bare repo as a remote
cd /path/to/your/existing/repo
git remote add bare_repo file:///path/to/new/bare/repo
```

This will create three new repositories on the VM. The bare repository is setup to allow both of the developers to push their changes to a common repository while the existing repository can pull from. You, of course, will have to use the common commands with interacting with a remote to push each persons changes, merge conflict, and pull changes into the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to **make two user accounts** on your VM? If so, you could each work under your own account but in the same repo.

```
# Use --global to set name and email for each user:
git config --global user.name "Taco John"
git config --global user.email "taco_john@git-scm.org"

# Use --system to set configuration for both users.
git config --system core.autocrlf input
```

**Pro:**

- This does just what you want.
- Separate IDE settings for each user.
- Separate browsing history and stackoverflow logins.

**Contra:**

- Need time to switch users. But hey, it's not about playing HoMM3 in hot-seat mode. :)

Also, I support previous commenters in the point that it's best to also have a separate repos for all users. Sharing a single repo will lead you to a mess and misunderstanding. If you have the resourses - **make separate repos for each user**.